# checking if predicate should return true or false not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to discern if the predicate returns truthy in all instances of a javascript object. 
my code is not performing as expected and I am not sure why, could use some help/guidance on where I am going wrong as I am not matching correct results in all test cases. I want to check the value of the key/value pair to catch the case where the value isNAN but cannot workout how to do it. updated code is below, its a work in progress, I will refactor it once I have a working solution.

[currentcode](https://repl.it/Bu0O)

testcases should return false but do not 
every([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male", "age": 0}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male", "age": 3}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female", "age": 5}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female", "age": 4}], "age")

every([{"name": "Pete", "onBoat": true}, {"name": "Repeat", "onBoat": true}, {"name": "FastFoward", "onBoat": null}], "onBoat")

Comment: After adding a closing `}`, [the code seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/wyc0euz3/) (changed `for..in` to `for` though). I can't fully understand, why these `every` calls should return `false`, `age` is a property in all objects in the first argument, and `onBoat` can be found in all objects in the second snippet. Notice, that `hasOwnProperty` tests for property existense, not the value of it.

Comment: When do you expect `collection[c][pre] == pre` to be true? Isn't that testing for a property where the property name equals the value?

Comment: Could you provide a js-fiddle ? It would be easier to understand.

Comment: Please tell us, what you expect your code to do, and why it should do that.

Answer (score 0):

I tidied up your code a little:

```
function propertyExists(array,property)
{
    var hasProperty = true;

    array.forEach(function(element)
    {
        if(!element.hasOwnProperty(property))
        {
            hasProperty = false;
        }
    });
    return hasProperty;
}
```

Explanation:

The code loops over the Array and checks if the property does exist for every element.
If it does it moves on to the next one.
If not it sets the flag `hasProperty` to `false`.
When the forEach loop reaches the end of the array the value of `hasProperty` is returned.

I am aware the this is probably not the most efficient way to do this but it is the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: Looks like OP wanted to check for value of the properties instead of the existense, the question is very unclear though.

Comment: If so the code could easily be changed to do that by just replacing the if condition.

Comment: I am working through some exercises on freecodecamp, this is the problem I was given. I submitted a bug report as I think the testcase return values are off.

Comment: Can you send me a link to that exercise please ?

Comment: sorry I cannot link directly due to their site, due to url encoding.

Comment: If i understand the exercise test cases correct you would have to test the value of the property for a valid value as well. This would however require a table of valid values for each property to validate against.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105686/discussion-between-webdev8183-and-lukas-gossmann).

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to pass the test cases by adding a check if the value existed filtering out the falsy values, I used a series of if statements to do it, though I suppose there are better methods, I have trouble wrapping my head around accessing javascript objects so this was a tough one for me. 
[Bonfire Everything be True](https://repl.it/Bu0O/2)

This is from FreeCodeCamp, since the editor doesn't like my code formatting I am just linking to the answer.